# LINQ get difference of two lists -> preserve duplicates

Tags: linq

Assuming two lists A and B

```
Dim A as New List(Of String) ( {"011", "011", "012", "001"})
Dim B as New List(Of String) ( {"011", "012", "111"});
```

I would like to get the difference from A to B, which is in this example: `[ "011", "001" ]`

Both lists A and B may contain duplicate entries. IF List A contains a duplicate element *e* and List B has the same value *e* only once // less times than A, than the result list should contain `(times e in A) - (times e in B)` *e*'s

For example:

```
["001", "001", "001", "002"] ~ ["001", "001", "003" ] -> ["001", "002"]
```

A solution to this problem is trivial in a classical way of programming but I would like to have a (shorter) solution with LINQ but so far I could not find a working piece of code because `Intersect, Except and Union` all cut away the duplicates which I need to preserve.

I'd be happy to see a simple LINQ solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tmp = b.ToList();
var result = a.Where(s => !tmp.Remove(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you need `!tmp.Contains(s) || `? I think you can get away without it.

Comment: I like this, it preserves the order of `a` in the same way that `Except` etc. do. Maybe you could speed it up a bit by making `tmp` a dictionary or something, but for a two-liner this is nice.

Comment: @BorisB. the solution cannot use a HashSet! ["a","a","a"]~["a","a"] -> ["a"] but with a HashSet you get ->["a","a"] as a result (which is wrong!)

Comment: @juq: Yep, two strings with same content have the same identity, will revert the answer to list.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that cleanly uses `ToLookup` might be worthwhile - especially if the lists get large.

Here it is:

```
Dim AL = A.ToLookup(Function (x) x)
Dim BL = B.ToLookup(Function (x) x)

Dim C = _
    AL _
        .SelectMany(Function (xs) xs.Skip(BL(xs.Key).Count())) _
        .ToList()
```

Or, in c#:

```
var AL = A.ToLookup(x => x);
var BL = B.ToLookup(x => x);

var C =
    AL
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.Skip(BL[xs.Key].Count()))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: that is a nice implementation but both my lists contain 0 - 10 (max!) Elements, usually 2-4, so I think the overhead created with creation of the lookups is too much for what I want to achive! Thanks for the idea, regards

Comment: @juq - Overhead because the lists are too small? The code is running on an advanced modern hardware, right? You should only be worried if your lists are huge. What you should worry about is maintainability. And then you want to have the simplest code possible.